# How To Get data From Request Login Form Laravel

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I have a problem, i need get data request from other field on login form to dashboard.

Login Form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g560x.png)

My Login Controller, and i use default auth from laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    public function username(){
        return 'username';
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

My AuthentictesUser

```
<?php

    namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Tahun;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

    trait AuthenticatesUsers
    {
        use RedirectsUsers, ThrottlesLogins;


        public function showLoginForm()
        {
            $tahuns = \DB::table('tahuns')->where('active','<>', '2')
            ->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
            return view('auth.login', compact('tahuns'));
        }

        public function login(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validateLogin($request);

            if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

                return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            }

            if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
                return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            }

            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }

        protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                $this->username() => 'required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
                'tahun' => 'required|string',
            ]);
        }

        protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
        {
            return $this->guard()->attempt(
                $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
            );
        }

        protected function credentials(Request $request)
        {
            return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        }

        protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
        {
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

            return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                    ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
        {
            //
        }

        protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
        {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                $this->username() => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]);
        }

        public function username()
        {
            return 'email';
        }

        public function logout(Request $request)
        {
            $this->guard()->logout();

            $request->session()->invalidate();

            return redirect('/');
        }
            protected function guard()
            {
                return Auth::guard();
            }
        }
```

How if i use data from fill tahun(year) on login form?
And i need send data from login form to my dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to replace the trait since you can simply override the trait methods in your `LoginController`, just like you did with `username()`.

Override `public function showLoginForm()` and return your custom view.

Override `protected function validateLogin(Request $request)` to validate your new fields.

Finally, override `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` and save the `tahun` data or return a redirect response.

Comment: Thanks, Solved Problem

Comment: You're welcome. And please don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).